# What does "this" refer in generic subclass in java?

Tags: java, generics, this, subclass

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Tree<E> {
    private class Node<E> {
        private ArrayList<Node<E>> list = new ArrayList<Node<E>> ();
        private Node<E> parent = null;
        private E element = null;
        public Node (E e, Node<E> p) {
            element = e; // (1)
            //this.element = e; <- difference?
            parent = p;
        }

        public Node (E e) {
            element = e; // (2)
            //this.element = e; <- difference?
        }

        public void setElement (E e) {
            element = e; // (3)
            //this.element = element; <- difference?
        }

        public E getElement () {
            return element;
        }

        public void addChild (E e) {
            Node<E> node = new Node<E> (element);
        }

        public void addParent (Node<E> node) {
            parent.addParent(this);
            this.parent
        }

        public void getChildren (Node<E> node) {

        }
    }
}
```

So basically, this is my unfinished test project class, and I am really confused what I really should use to pass out the parameter into the variable.

As I indicated in the code, I would like to know the difference between using "this" function and without putting "this" function on the prefix.

For example, in number 1 in the comment, what will happen if I change that to the below comment: this.element?

Also same as in number 2 and 3, am I supposed to use this? instead of just element?

or does this work as same as not using it, no matter what in this case?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. If there is no ambiguity against parameter with the same name, naming `element` or `parent` is exactly the same as naming them as `this.element` or `this.parent`.

Comment: Oh I have another question. In this code fragment: "parent.addParent(this);" what does "this" refer to in that code? is it parent node which is private Node<E> parent = null;?

Comment: `this` refers to the current object, it is the same as when you use `self` or `I` in your native language, it is a special word that refers to the one that pronounces it.

Answer (score 0):

In this case it does not change anything. Because your method parameter and class property have different names. The reason for this keyword is to avoid [hiding class property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) by local method property.

This example should explain it:

This will assign method parameter to itself, thus Node.element will not be initialized.

```
public Node (E element) {
   element = element; 
}
```

This will assign method parameter element to Node.element property, thus this property will be initialized.

```
public Node (E element) {
   this.element = element; 
}
```

Comment: Oh, so the initialization depends on the name when if I don't use "this"? Thank you!

Comment: In short: when you have class.name property and method property name, then method property name 'hides' the class property. By 'this' you are telling the compiler to use class property, not the local. But this has sense only is both names are the same, or you like to emphasise that this is a class property.

Answer (score 0):

Number (1) and (2), it makes no difference. When referring to a member variable, you can use `this.` to make it more explicit.

Number (3), you'll have a problem if you use `this.element = element` because this is equivalent to doing `this.element = this.element`, so you never actually assign the parameter to the field.

Answer (score 0):

In this case usage of `this` has nothing to do with generics.

You only need to use `this.element` instead of element if you have something which "shadows" your field. For instance:

```
    public void setElement (E element) {
        this.element = element;
    }
```

Obviously, you can't write `element = element;`.

Now to your questions:

```
    public Node (E e, Node<E> p) {
        element = e; // (1)
        //this.element = e; <- difference?
        parent = p;
    }
```

No.

```
    public Node (E e) {
        element = e; // (2)
        //this.element = e; <- difference?
    }
```

No.

```
    public void setElement (E e) {
        element = e; // (3)
        //this.element = element; <- difference?
    }
```

Yes. You assign the field to itself, so that would be a bug.

> For example, in number 1 in the comment, what will happen if I change that to the below comment: this.element?

Technically nothing different.

> Also same as in number 2 and 3, am I supposed to use this? instead of just element?

Technically this makes no difference.

Practically as a matter of style, I prefer *always* using `this` when I refer to fields.